# node.js TypeError: Path must be a string. Received null

Tags: node.js, sockets

I was recently working on a javascript that uses socket.io,node.js and express.js.
here is the server code.

```js
var
    port = +process.argv[2] || 8080,

    sanitizer = require('validator').sanitize,
    express = require('express'),

    server = express.createServer(),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    chat = io.of('/chat'),
    canvas = io.of('/canvas')
;

function sanitize(string) {
    return sanitizer(string).entityDecode()
}

server.listen(port);

server.get(/(^\/.*$)/, function(request, response) {
    var fileName = request.params[0];
    if (fileName == '/')
        fileName = '/index.html';
    response.sendfile(__dirname + '/client' + fileName);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('setName', function (name) {
        name = sanitize(name);
        socket.set('name', name);
        socket.broadcast.emit('receive', {
            sender:'Server',
            message:name + ' has joined.'
        })
    });

    socket.on('send', function (message) {
        socket.get('name', function(error, name) {
            if (name)
                socket.broadcast.emit('receive', {
                    sender:name,
                    message:sanitize(message)
                })
        })
    });

    socket.on('draw', function (command) {
        io.sockets.emit('draw', command)
    });

    socket.on('updateCursor', function(position) {
        socket.get('name', function(error, name) {
            if (name)
                socket.broadcast.emit('updateCursor', {
                    name:name,
                    position:position
                });
        });
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        socket.get('name', function(error, name) {
            if (name) {
                socket.broadcast.emit('receive', {
                    sender:'Server',
                    message:name + ' has left.'
                });
                socket.broadcast.emit('removeCursor', name);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

I am able to set up the server successfully, but when I use the localhost on the browser, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Path must be a string. Received null
>       at assertPath (path.js:8:11)
>       at win32.join (path.js:221:5)
>       at exports.send (C:\Users\Akshay\Desktop\whiteboard-master\whiteboard-master\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\static.js:127:20)
>       at ServerResponse.res.sendfile (C:\Users\Akshay\Desktop\whiteboard-master\whiteboard-master\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:186:3)
>       at C:\Users\Akshay\Desktop\whiteboard-master\whiteboard-master\server.js:23:14
>       at callbacks (C:\Users\Akshay\Desktop\whiteboard-master\whiteboard-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:272:11)
>       at param (C:\Users\Akshay\Desktop\whiteboard-master\whiteboard-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:246:11)
>       at pass (C:\Users\Akshay\Desktop\whiteboard-master\whiteboard-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:253:5)
>       at Router._dispatch (C:\Users\Akshay\Desktop\whiteboard-master\whiteboard-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:5)
>       at Object.Router.middleware [as handle] (C:\Users\Akshay\Desktop\whiteboard-master\whiteboard-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:45:10)

I had developed this using the unstable v0.5.8 windows binary version of node.
but I am currently running the 4.4.5 version.

Please help me, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to tell from the sample code you've pasted because your stack trace references line 45 in your index.js as the source of the problem (`C:\Users\Akshay\Desktop\whiteboard-master\whiteboard-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:45:10`) but when I look at your sample/pasted code in an IDE, it's not doing anything there. The only call to `sendfile` (referenced further up in your stack trace) is earlier in the script.

Assuming that's the location of your issue, you should `console.log()` or otherwise debug the value of the path/filename you're attempting to send to the visitor. Note that in Windows, path delimiters are `\` not `/`. You should use `path.join()` to form the final path to the file served. The ExpressJS examples illustrate this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try that. I tried to run the index.html file seperately, it ran without a hitch, but i will check that again